# Don't understand why white resigned

Tags: resigning

In the [2017 Women's World Chess Championship match](http://www.chessdom.com/2017-women-world-chess-championship-live/) (Round 3, game 2) between Yang Shen (white) against Nana Dzagnidze (black) I don't understand why white resigned. There was not a time control issue and it appeared that white could at least get a draw.

```
[FEN ""]
[StartPly "77"]

1. e4 c5
2. Ne2 e5
3. Nbc3 Nc6
4. g3 g6
5. Bg2 Bg7
6. d3 Nge7
7. Bg5 d6
8. Nd5 h6
9. Be3 Nxd5
10. exd5 Nd4
11. Nc1 O-O
12. c3 Nf5
13. Bd2 Ne7
14. Ne2 Bf5
15. Be3 Qd7
16. Qd2 Bh3
17. Bxh3 Qxh3
18. c4 b5
19. Nc3 bxc4
20. dxc4 e4
21. O-O-O Rfb8
22. b3 a5
23. Nb5 a4
24. b4 Qd7
25. bxc5 Rxb5
26. cxb5 Qxb5
27. Qc2 Qb4
28. Rd2 Bc3
29. Re1 Rc8
30. Kd1 f5
31. cxd6 Qxd6
32. Bf4 Qd7
33. d6 Bxd2
34. Qxd2 Qb5
35. dxe7 Qb1+
36. Ke2 Qb5+
37. Ke3 Qb6+
38. Ke2 Qb5+
39. Kd1 0-1
```

Comment: Could you make this question self-contained by adding the diagram of the final position? You can find some help on how to create diagrams in the help centre.

Comment: Unless we talk about a different game, that game ended in a draw.  Since Yang Shen had lost the first game against Nana Dzagnidze this meant that she did not make it to the next round.

Comment: @jknappen  Where is this "help" for the diagrams?  I've searched and searched . . .

Comment: @pokep: I don't know if this is what jknappen referred to, but I always use http://meta.chess.stackexchange.com/questions/179/how-do-i-add-a-replayer-to-my-post and the answers therein.

Answer (score 6):

The game ended in a draw. Chessbomb isn't an official source, but it recorded the game as a [draw](https://www.chessbomb.com/arena/2017-womens-world-championship/06-Shen_Yang-Dzagnidze_Nana), and the comments there indicate that the game was originally reported (by the digital board, perhaps) as a win for Black, but it has been corrected to a draw. These glitches happen from time to time.

As for the position: it doesn't seem possible for white to escape perpetual check, and black cannot force a mate and is far behind in material. Therefore, it's a draw.